# Why does javascript persist local variable reassignments that occur in outside functions without having to capture the return values?

Tags: javascript, ruby, scope, variable-assignment

I'm a ruby programmer, so where I come from customarily, if you had something like this:

```
  def addone(x)
    x+1
  end

  def ruby_assignment_behavior(x)
    addone(x)
    puts "x equals " + x
  end
```

running that last method would result in the following:

```
ruby_assignment_behavior(1)
#=> "x equals 1"
```

in javascript, something equivalent to this would return `x equals 2`, I think.

I discovered this unique quality of javascript (relative to ruby) after studying this code (fetches user gps coordinates)

```
var currPosition;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    updatePosition(position);
    $("#lat").html(position.coords.latitude;);
    $("#lng").html(position.coords.longitude);  
};

function updatePosition(position) {
    currPosition = position;
}
```

Why is it that inside of the `getCurrentPosition` function, the `position` variable is updated with the return value of `updatePosition()`, even though `position` is a local variable inside of a closure(?)

ALSO:
I'm curious, in the javascript code sample, is having that `updatePosition` function outside of `getCurrentPosition` necessary, and if so, why is that the case? Does that `currPosition` variable which was defined in the outermost scope somehow carry the reassigned `position` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two pieces of code are very different. In your Ruby code, you are changing the variable value. Since the variable is local, as you correctly state, the change is not reflected outside the scope.

In your JavaScript code, you are changing the internal state of an object pointed to by the variable. The variable itself does not change.

In this respect, Ruby and JavaScript behave identically.

```
var a = { count: 0 };
function increment(x) {
  x.count++; // variable changed, changing referenced object state
}
increment(a);
console.log(a.count);
// => 1
```

is equivalent to

```
a = { count: 0 }
def increment(x)
  x[:count] += 1 # variable changed, changing referenced object state
end
increment(a)
puts a[:count]
# => 1
```

while

```
var b = { count: 0 };
function increment(x) {
  x = { count: x.count + 1 }; // changing variable's reference
}
increment(b);
console.log(b.count);
// => 0
```

is equivalent to

```
b = { count: 0 }
def increment(x)
  x = { count: x[:count] + 1 } # changing variable's reference
end
increment(b)
puts b[:count]
# => 0
```

`var currPosition` outside the function declares the variable `currPosition` to be in the scope that is wider than the function, kind of but not quite like using `$currPosition` in Ruby. This allows the function to assign the value to a variable that will be visible oustide it:

```
var c = 0; // outer scope
function update() {
  c = 1;
}
update();
console.log(c);
// 1
```

but

```
function update() {
  var d = 0; // inner scope
  d = 1;
}
update();
console.log(d);
// undefined
```

In Ruby, variables are not allowed to jump function (method) scopes like that, but you can use `@a`, `@@a` or `$a` to access an outer scope (instance, class or global):

```
def update
  c = 1 # local scope
end
update
puts c
# => Error
```

but

```
@d = nil # instance scope
def update
  @d = 1
end
update
puts @d
# => 1
```

However, there are similar scope effects with blocks in Ruby as with functions in JavaScript:

```
e = nil # outer scope
1.times do
  e = 1
end
e
# => 1
```

but

```
1.times do
  f = 1 # inner scope
end
f
# => Error
```

Comment: in your code sample starting with `var a = 0; // outerscope`, are those two code examples meant to be interpreted as being done in sequence within the same outer scope?

Comment: Ah, no, independent pieces of code (if you execute them one after another, there will be pollution). I should probably rename the variables to avoid that... EDIT: done.

Comment: Were the javascript `c` & `d` examples run with the same variable names in sequence, wouldn't the second `c` operation transmute `c` into a local variable inside a closure and thus make it return null outside of that closure? I'll test it out ... yup, sure does.

Comment: No. There is no transmuting. In ES5, a variable exists at the scope where it is declared (using `var`) and all scopes inside it; if there is no `var`, the variable is global (widest scope). Thus, `c` exists in the whole snippet (which is all one scope); `d` exists only within the function.

Comment: Oh, if they were all `c` and you ran them one after another? Then the redefined `update` will have a local variable `c` which will have nothing to do with the outer-scope variable `c`; whatever the redefined `update` does will not affect the outer-scope `c`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I must have made a typo. Did it again and it remained equal to 1. Anyway, thanks man. That was one hell of an answer